# Maven Repository Manager - Nexus vs Artifactory for Java Dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, nexus, artifactory

We have developed Java based micro services using spring framework where we have dependencies in the form of JAR's. I just wanted to know that which maven repository manager is more useful and efficient. By efficient I mean

1. Fetching the dependencies from the remote repository at faster rate.
2. Fetching third party dependencies (Rarely used) easily.
3. Taking less  deployment time in Docker environment.
4. Good consistency check and self healing mechanism.
5. Pricing.

Comment: 1. It's depending on the network latency.. 2. also. 3. depends on your deployment pipeline.. 4. What is in your opinion a good consistency check and self healing mechanism? 5. Take a look into the product sites...

Answer (score 1):

For our big projects with similar scheme (micro services, spring) we are using JFrog Artifactory.

Do not know your budget, but here you may find pricing:

[JFROG](https://jfrog.com/pricing/)

Regarding your requirements - it's supports that all.

Comment: Actually I am more concerned about third party dependencies, there are some dependencies that needs to be added manually in the repository manager coz repo manager doesn't pick them up from public repositories. This is the case that happened using Nexus, dont know in case of Jfro Artifacrtory.

Comment: but when you run project (Microservice) first time, dependency fetching time is greater in case of artifatory as compare to nexus, because of which i am confused

Comment: If you have to add them manually than those artifacts are not available in Central and you have to do that manually for Artifactory and for Nexus...If they are available from Central and they are not picked up your configuration is simply wrong...